# Select all elements with exact attr value and value, wants to return true or false JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

I have a little problem with jquery. I have this code:

```
if ($("select[rendelo='" + rendelo + "'][nap='" + nap + "'][napszak='" + napszak + "']").val() == 0) { 

            alert('sth');

            } else {

            alert('sthelse');

            }
```

I have multiple select menus (around 200) and I grouped them by different attributes. I want to know if all the above code gives me true, and if yes, then alert sth. If not all (even if one is false) alert sthelse.

I have 4 select menus with these selectors:

```
$("select[rendelo='" + rendelo + "'][nap='" + nap + "'][napszak='" + napszak + "']")
```

An example to the select menu, as requested:

```
<select nap="1" napszak="1" rendelo="1" sor="1" oszlop="1" class="selectMenu">
<option value="0"></option>
<option value="6">sth</option>
</select>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please show sample of at least 2 `<select>` html. The logic won't do what you want but selector may or may not be right either depending on the html. Also we have no idea what those variables are. See [mcve]

Comment: <select nap="1" napszak="1" rendelo="1" sor="1" oszlop="1" class="selectMenu">
<option value="0"></option>
<option value="6">sth</option>
</select>

Comment: So that means you have 4 that are exactly the same for each variable? Again, a proper, runnable example would help

Comment: yes, I selected 4 different select menus with that selector, and I want to check if all of them have value 0. I have "sor" 1 or 2 and "oszlop" 1 and 2.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wd32eg90/3/

Comment: Is there a parent container that holds each group of 4? that would simplfy it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `filter()` to check length of matching collection. This assumes you have 4 with all same attributes which is still not clear

```
var $zeroSelects = $("select[rendelo='" + rendelo + "'][nap='" + nap + "'][napszak='" + napszak + "']").filter(function(){
   return $(this).val() === '0'
}) 

if($zeroSelects.length === 4){
   // all true
}else{
   // at least one not true
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It's working like a charm! 

And sorry for not being easily understandable. I'm new in this field.